# Reasons for using RPC

Tags: c, rpc

I am planning on writing a client/server application. Both the server and client components will be written in C. I was looking at C socket libraries which can help me with this project and I started to read about RPC.

Is RPC used in most client/server programs?

What are the reasons to use RPC as opposed to writing your own socket code?

Comment: If you want results (instead of learning), use whatever existing framework and protocols. Sun RPC, or XMLRPC, or SOAP, or some message queue like 0MQ, whatever. Don't reinvent the wheel, except for learning purposes (and even then, when you really need to do dome "real" code, use existing solution instead of what you created when learning).

Answer (score 0):

ONC RPC originated in the 1980's and has been worked on since then; consequently, it's very robust, efficient, and documented.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that rpc is just one option, a framework, you can use to create server/client architecture c apps but you certainly could write your own using c socket libraries, etc? Would an analogy by like jgroups in the java world? I can use jgroups for server client apps but its just an option of many??